exe file of my scrapy spider extracts only the first page
I have this spider script:
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "book"
    start_urls = {
        'https://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-1.html'
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        for book in response.css("li.col-xs-6.col-sm-4.col-md-3.col-lg-3"):
            yield {
                "price": book.css("div.product_price p.price_color::text").get(),
                "name": book.css("h3 a::attr(title)").get()
            }
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings={
            "FEEDS": {
                "items.json": {"format": "json"},
            },
            "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO" 
        }
    )
    process.crawl(BookSpider)
    process.start()

When I run this script from my IDE or using scrapy crawl book -O book.json it works well, but when I build and run an exe file from this script using python -m PyInstaller bookScraper.py --onefile it scrapes only the first page and finishes the spider.
I'm new in scrapy and am trying to find solution to this problem, but I can`t find anything useful.
I tried to find some other solution for iterating through all pages, but have the same result.
